# Dataclass code that sets slots=true if python version allows

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, slots

I'm writing a module that needs to run under both Python 3.8 and Python 3.10. I want to have dataclasses that have slots (`@dataclasses.dataclass(slots=True)`) in Python 3.10 for the purposes of type checking (both static and runtime). Is there a `from __future__` import that will make this compatible with Python 3.8? If not, what is the most pytype-friendly way of emulating one?

Additional note: I'm currently using the `dataclasses_json` module, which to the best of my knowledge is not compatible with `attrs`. Otherwise I could switch from `dataclasses` to `attrs` and easily solve the problem.

Comment: Make new decortor that returns https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html and use instead of standard dataclasses decorators ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't *need* the slots feature in the older version, that is easy.

`from __future__ ...` imports as reserved for language features that change the way the syntax itself works. The `slots` feature in dataclasses is just another parameter in the library, so, logically, it does not get such a workaround.

As it is, one have to conditionally insert the slots argument on the decorator call. Python 3.8 decorator expressions are not the same as general expressions - but we can add the inline logic to the arguments part only - that is executed before the call itself, so it will work.

Python also has no syntax to directly add a keyword parameter in a call or not, according to a condition - but since keyword parameters can be extracted from dictionaries with the use of `**`, it can be done indirectly.

Therefore, the lines bellow should work:

```
import dataclasses
import sys
...

py310 = sys.version_info.minor >= 10 or sys.version_info.major > 3

@dataclasses.dataclass(**({"slots": True} if py310 else {}))
class MyData:
   ...
```

Comment: yes, it was reversed. thanks.,

Comment: A simplification I discovered when exploring this solution: you can directly compare `sys.version_info >= (3, 10)`.